# Strange behaviour by Apache poi while reading excel file

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I have successfully read the excel file using Apache POI library. But, I am receiving a strange behavior from it which I am unsure why it is happening.

If I create a new excel file with the adjustment of the required data just as this:

[image]

The empty cell that is set at the first of the email column is not read at all(ignored).

But if I modify the file and change the font or font size of the same file, Apache POI reads the empty email cell successfully.

**Default Font setting (Empty Cell not read):**

[image]

The array that I receive from the method:

```
[Hari Krishna, 445444, 986544544]
```

**Changed Font Size (Empty Cell read Successfully):**

[image]

The array that I receive from the method:

```
[Hari Krishna, 445444, 986544544, ]
```

And here is the full code that I've used to read through the excel file:

```
 public static List importExcelFile(String filePath, String fileName) {
    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(Locale.UK);
    // stores data from excel file
    List excelDataList = new ArrayList();
    try {
      // Import file from source destination
      FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath.concat(File.separator.concat(fileName))));

      // Get the workbook instance for XLS file
      XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
      // workbook.setMissingCellPolicy(Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
      // Get first sheet from the workbook
      XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
      // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
      Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
      // Skip first row, since it is header row
      rowIterator.next();
      while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        int nextCell = 1;
        int currentCell = 0;
        // add data of each row
        ArrayList rowList = new ArrayList();
        // For each row, iterate through each columns
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
          Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
          currentCell = cell.getColumnIndex();
          if (currentCell >= nextCell) {
            int diffInCellCount = currentCell - nextCell;
            for (int nullLoop = 0; nullLoop <= diffInCellCount; nullLoop++) {
              rowList.add(" ");
              nextCell++;
            }
          }
          switch (cell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
              rowList.add(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
              break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
              if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                String date = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                rowList.add(date);
              } else {
                rowList.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());
              }
              break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
              rowList.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
              break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
              rowList.add(" ");
              break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
              rowList.add(" ");
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
          nextCell++;
        }
        excelDataList.add(rowList);
      }
      file.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println(e.toString());
      return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }
    return excelDataList;

  }
```

Comment: Did you [try reading the Apache POI docs on iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that when you set the font size of the cell, Excel needs a way to know that the cell has a different font (and generally, `CellStyle`).  When you changed the font size from the default, then Excel created a blank cell and gave it a cell style - font size of 10.  Because the `CellStyle` is an attribute of the `Cell`, Excel needed a `Cell` so it could store the `CellStyle` for it.

When you read the `Cell`s with an `Iterator<Cell>`, it will only return those `Cell`s that exist.  Before your font size change, the "Email" cell for "Hari Krishna" didn't exist.  After your font size change, now the "Email" cell for "Hari Krishna" exists, even if it's blank.

If you want the blank value, even if there is no font size change, then you can't use the `Iterator`, because it won't return that `Cell` -- it doesn't exist.  You can use a standard `for` loop on the `Row` object, using a [`MissingCellPolicy` of `CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).

If you want to skip the blank value, regardless of whether there is a font size change, then you should simply skip the cells that have a type of `CELL_TYPE_BLANK`.  Remove that case from your `switch` statement.